# Copy only file that matches variable string

Tags: powershell, copy, copy-item

I'm trying to copy files based on the hour of `Get-Date`'s time stamp to match it to files that are saved from a different source in a `filename_10_00.ext` structure. If I use 24 hour time, I can use the hour of `Get-Date` to determine which file I'm looking for. (This is to run hourly backups)

This is what I have:

```
$current_time = Get-Date
$hour_var = $current_time.Hour
Get-ChildItem -Path \\Path\To\Source | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -match "$hour_var"
} | Copy-Item -Destination \\Path\To\Destination
```

Can somebody tell me why it can't seem to match based on the PowerShell I've provided?

I am looking for pure PowerShell with ideally no imported modules.

Comment: Please show sample output of `Get-ChildItem -Path \\Path\To\Source` as well as the desired and actual output of `Get-ChildItem -Path \\Path\To\Source | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "$hour_var"}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no sample output. The desired output would be that it uses $hour_var as a regular expression to scan all files for the "filename_hh_mm_ss.ext" to compare the returned hour from $hour_var with the hour in hh from the filename.

Comment: If `Get-ChildItem -Path \\Path\To\Source` doesn't produce any output, why are you surprised that nothing is being copied?

Comment: My apologies. I misunderstood the output of Get-ChildItem -Path \\Path\To\Source as the output of the copy. I can see the files in that folder when I Write-host $test after I assign the Get-ChildItem command to $test

Answer (score 1):

Assuming leading zeroes in the hour format try this:

```
$Src = "\\Path\To\Source"
$Dst = "\\Path\To\Destination"

$CurrHour = (Get-Date).Hour.ToString('00')
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src *_??_??.ext | 
  Where-Object BaseName -match "^.*_$CurrHour_\d{2}$" | 
    Copy-Item -Destination $Dst -whatif
```

If output looks OK remove the `-whatif`

Comment: Using this example doesn't seem to yield any output on -whatif and removing the -whatif doesn't seem to copy anything. I've revised it with the actual source and destination path along with file extension to give a more accurate example. Src and Dts are shared folders on the PC and I'm running as admin.


`$Src = "\\WIN-F4GLTG2LGVN\Source"`
`$Dst = "\\WIN-F4GLTG2LGVN\Destination"`

`$CurrHour = (Get-Date).Hour.ToString('00')`
`Get-ChildItem -Path $Src filename_??_??.txt | 
  Where-Object BaseName -match "^filename_$CurrHour_\d{2}$" | 
    Copy-Item -Destination $Dst -whatif`

Comment: Did you adapt the pseudo `filename` to fit your environment?

Comment: I didn't but I was more concerned that shared folders might be causes issues than the filenames so I wanted them to be more strict. For testing purposes, filename_12_00.txt would be a legitimate example.

Comment: Changed above to be less restrictive it uses a wildcard `*._??_??.ext` to filter filenames in the gci and a pattern `"^.*_$CurrHour_\d{2}$"` to match on the hour. This worked in my local tests.

Comment: Works great. Thanks for your time!